# How to Reset Dragon Miner 1TH/s IP Address?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-hardware

How can I reset the IP address of a Dragon Miner 1TH/s machine?

Mistakenly, I entered the wrong IP in the miner when changing the network IP address, and now my miner is not visible on the network. What I entered was like "IP 192.168.1.100.4".

So how can I reset my miner?  It has the SD card option.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.

I got it to work again, by updating the miners firmware:

- I flashed this image to an SD card: https://www.dropbox.com/s/clafawqo2oo4jrb/dragon_miner_mxnschmod_firmwarev1.2_20160108_ip254.rar?dl=1.
- I then popped it into the miner and waited a few minutes.

When I logged into the IP, it wass working better than the original. You can use the `win32flasher` tool to do the flashing of the SD card.

Comment: Careful about installing firmware from unknown sources, it may have been modified to reroute the hashing power to someone else, or do other nefarious things.

Answer (score 0):

Okay first go to this link: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1307157.0 
take the outer side case off the miner and remove the sd card (while its off ;) ) pop the sd card into pc and format it. flash the image i linked to you in my other comment with win32flasher. give it 10min have a beer or a ciggy :) once its done pop the sd card back into the miner be careful as it can be a fiddly ****** try not to knock anything out of place but if you do just check before turning it on. turn it on and wait 3-5 minutes the lights should be steady green now. dont worry if it doesn't show an ip address on the screen it didnt for me. go to 192.168.1.254/ that is the address your miner is configured to go on now. the login details are admin with no password. you can now go into config and add your pool details. for using SSH its pi and the password is raspberry Hope i was of more help, feel free to pm me if you need anymore help

Comment: Careful about installing firmware from unknown sources, it may have been modified to reroute the hashing power to someone else, or do other nefarious things.